# String response from servlet to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I have this code in java:

```
public static String Login (HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        if(Auth.AuthCheck(request.getParameter("user"), request.getParameter("pass"))) {
            HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
            sesion.setAttribute("user", request.getParameter("user"));
            
            return "success";
            
        }else {
            return "fail";

        }
```

"AuthCheck" is a method I created inside a class called "Auth", It receives 2 string parameters (user and password from an html file), this is me trying to make a Login and the conde from above is a method ment to validate a user in the database, it works fine, the problem is that the string "success" or "fail" do return correctly apparently, and in the javascript side, it receives and shows in console the string correctly but when I try to use it in an "if" for some reason it won't work and it's driving me crazy. Heres the javascript code, where you can see the fetch api im using

```js
var myFormLogin = document.getElementById('form');
var myButtonLogin = document.getElementById('IdBotonLogin');


const sendLogin = (e)=>{
 e.preventDefault();

const formData = new FormData(myFormLogin);


fetch('http://localhost:8080/prim/Login', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData        
}).then((Response)=>{
    return Response.text();
}).then((text)=>{
    
    console.log(text); 
    
    if(text == "success"){
        location.href = 'redirect.html';
    }
    
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.error(error);
})

};
myButtonLogin.onclick = sendLogin;
```

As you can see, in the "if" above(javascript code) I'm comparing the String recieved from the servlet side with the string "success" and it's supposed to be "true" but it says "false" when I put the line console.log(text == "success"); down console.log(text);, another thing that is very interesting is that if I put this text+='pppp'; it prints the following:

```
success
pppp
```

They are aparted, not in the same line, next to each other... for the rest of the code it "works", it's just this thing.

Comment: I can't edit the post, Just in case it's not clear, what i want to know is why is the "if" not working here... is it that the String received from the servlet is not an actual string? or am i doing a very simple mistake?

Comment: Hi `trim` any white spaces i.e :`$.trim(text)` and then compare i.e: `if($.trim(text)== "success"){` and see if that works .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I jist tried that but it says "Loginjs.js:25 ReferenceError: $ is not defined at Loginjs.js:19" also the "success" and "pppp" are print in two different lines, one above and the other down, but it appears next to each other in my post

Comment: Hi , i didn't saw tag you have not use jquery that's why that error . Can you try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/eyckax6o/) way ?

Comment: It does work by itself, but not in my code, the first line would be more like this: var str = text +"pppp"; //text, and yet it prints it in two lines, if I create the string in the function's scope there's no problem, the thing is this "text" coming from the servlet as a response which seems to be a string but doesn't act like it. The "text" is the server side response and thats what I have to handle somehow to validate when a user logs in so I can redirect him to another page, and the one that edited my first post, thank you.

Comment: Hi why you are appending `"pppp"` to text  is it necessary  ? Also put space in between `var str = text +" pppp"` so now `split(" ")` will look space between two words.

Comment: Your servlet code is incomplete (please please [mcve] :/ ), but the symptoms so far suggest that you used `response.getWriter().println(string)` instead of `response.getWriter().print(string)`. Guess what that extra `ln` does ...

Comment: I'm sorry i did not make that clear, that was my attempt to make this "text" a string just in case it was not. I tried different ways but I'm always getting the same result. I just find funny that whenever i try to append another string to it, it places it under the text line and not next to it and without spaces  as it should be. I suspect this may be related to the problem.

Comment: Well well, the agony has come to an end, thank you MR. BalusC, you were absolutely right, the problem was as tiny as an ant after all but it caused me so much pain. Thank you and Swati.